# Can't use a saved instance/reference to make an association with another model

Tags: laravel, constraints, eloquent, belongs-to, relationships

Folks i have got something strange happening with eloquent and the database i can't seem to put a finger to it.
i have 3 models User > Gp1user > Worker in an inheritance hierachy with a one to one relationship between them.

this is the code from my controller

```
$user = User::find(1);
$gp1user = new Gp1user;
$gp1user->user()->associate($user);
$gp1user->save();

$worker = new Worker;
$worker->gp1user()->associate($gp1user);
$worker->save();
```

it seems even though `$gp1user` is saved, i can't use that reference to make the association with `$worker`. i get the error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`careers`.`workers`, CONSTRAINT `workers_gp1user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`gp1user_id`) REFERENCES `gp1users` (`user_id`)) (SQL: insert into `workers` (`gp1user_id`) values (0))
```

But if i do check the database, the `$gp1user` instance does exist. so i am only left with this option.

```
$user = User::find(1);

$gp1user = new Gp1user;
$gp1user->user()->associate($user);
$gp1user->save();

$worker = new Worker;
$worker->gp1user()->associate(Gp1user::find(9));
$worker->save();
```

i have to find the particular instance in the db an create a new instance using the `id`. which works, but doesnt because i have to check for the id in the db first.
why won't eloquent let me use the `$gp1user` reference?
i suspect its something to do with the foreign keys but i can't find anything wrong.

this is what my migrations (in different files) look like

```
Schema::create('users', function($table)
    {
        //
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('first_name', 128);
        $table->string('second_name', 128);
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->timestamps();
    });




Schema::create('gp1users', function($table)
    {

        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->unique('user_id')->primary();



    });



Schema::create('workers', function($table)
    {
        $table->integer('gp1user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('gp1user_id')->references('user_id')->on('gp1users');
        $table->unique('gp1user_id')->primary();



    });
```

my models

```
class User extends Eloquent {


public function gp1user()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Gp1user');
}

}



class Gp1user extends Eloquent {


protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
public $timestamps = false;


public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}

public function worker()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Worker');
}

}



class Worker extends Eloquent {


protected $primaryKey = 'gp1user_id';
public $timestamps = false;


public function gp1user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Gp1user');
}

}
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.  Unfortunately, I'm not yet sure why exactly.

```
$user = User::find(1);

$gp1user = new Gp1user;
$gp1user->user()->associate($user);

$worker = new Worker();
$worker->gp1user()->associate($gp1user);

$gp1user->save();
$worker->save();
```